# How does the skill damage work?

Tags: torchlight-2

My Eviscerate skill currently says:

> Inflicts 88% of Weapon DPS

Let's not take into account the extra DoT effect that this skill does.

Does that mean that attacking with this skill actually does *less* damage than attacking normally? Does it mean that it deals 88% of the total average damage I would deal per second in a single hit (this would make it a slight damage bonus, depending on my attack speed)?

Overall, what exactly does htis 88% represent?

Comment: Good question, if it only uses your damage and not your DPS, then having high weapon damage with low attack speed will serve skills better than the latter. Although it pretty clearly says DPS, casting speed is different than attack speed so I doubt it is affected by attack speed at all.

Comment: What class are you playing?

Comment: @badp Currently a Berserker, but it shouldn't make too much of a difference in finding the answer to this question. I imagine that weapon damage % on skills works the same way for all the classes.

Comment: Related: [How does dual wielding affect skills which depend on weapon dps](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85531/how-does-dual-wielding-affect-skills-which-depend-on-weapon-dps). That being said, i've actually been wondering it myself so i might test it out a bit :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First, the following tests have all been done with a **Level 2 Berserker** with **no** skillpoints or stat points invested on the dummy in the Estherian Enclave. Critical hits and fumbled attacks are completely excluded from every calculation aswell as attacks from both claws at the same time.

Secondly, this was an interesting thing to test and I'll have to explain a few things/assumptions before I get on with the more related results:

**How random is the damage ?**

Assuming a constant environment I would assume a constant damage result. This is however **not** the case, and thus all results by me (and others) will be subject to 'random' fluctuations. I tested this with a `45 dps claw` (36 physical damage every 0.8s) which gave me a weapon damage of `39-39`. I used no offhand and proceeded to hit (regular attack) the dummy like a madman. I hit either `34, 35 or 36` while i would have expected to hit 35 all the time.

**How to account for armor?**

In Torchlight 2, every damage you do is decreased by *an amount based on the armor value of your enemy*. Since all the damage in my tests was Physical Damage, we can focus only on physical armor, but there's no way of knowing the armor of your enemy as far as I know.

When I hit the dummy with my regular claws (`13 - 19 weapon damage`) I had hits variating between `10` and `17`. Removing 1 claw gave me `12 - 18 weapon damage` and hits between `9` and `16`. I then equiped my high dps claw which gave me `39 - 39 weapon damage` and got hits between `34` and `36` (avg. `35`).

From this I concluded the damage decrease done by the dummies armor **for this range of damage** is between `2` and `4`.

Note that I by no means claim that armor removes a linear amount of damage nor that it doesn't scale with your damage, level, ...

**Is everything an** `integer` **?**

That would be nice, but sadly: no.  A lot of calculations gave fractions/floating point numbers as a result. Since it's not very nice to display those everything has to be rounded to *an integer*. I do not know how it is programmed, but I assumed everything is **rounded to the nearest integer**. This seemed to be most of the time the case.

Now, let's get on with the real results!

**Scenario 1: 1 claw, no offhand**

With 1 claw in your righthand and no offhand, this does exactly as it says: it takes your claws dps, takes 88% of it and deals that amount as damage (the final result still has to include armor!). So the higher the dps of your claw, the higher the damage of **Eviscerate** will be.

With my `45 dps` claw I mentioned above, my Eviscerate hit for `37 - 39` (avg. `38`). Indeed, 88% of 45 is `40`. Giving this an armor penalty of `2` gives us the average Eviscerate damage.

Important to note is that this is **an increase** of damage compared to a regular attack. (an increase of `3 damage` in this case)

**Scenario 2: 2 claws, equal dps**

Now, how does the damage compare to scenario 1? Does it increase because of dual-wielding, is it the same, does it decrease?

- With 1 claw of `22 dps` I got Eviscerate hits of `12` to `20` (avg. `16`).
- With 2 claws of `22 dps` I got Eviscerate hits of `14` to `21` (avg. `18`).

Tada ! An increase. But by how much and why? I will return to this at the end of scenario 3.

**Scenario 3: 2 claws, different dps**

This is the part where it really becomes interesting.

- A 45 dps claw in right hand and a 22 dps claw in offhand gives me `41` to `43` damage hits.
- A 22 dps claw in right hand and a 45 dps claw in offhand gives me `14` to `21` damage hits.

So it's of the most benefit to ALWAYS put your highest dps weapon in your right hand.

Now with that last result in mind, we return to scenario 2, where we got **the same** damage as with a **22 dps** claw in our offhand (twice an average of `18`). So the stats of our offhand are not important, as long as it's a weapon (see later: shields) you will gain an increase in damage because of dual-wielding.

So how much is the increase for dual-wielding? I don't know but from these results it would seem like the increase is equal to `floor(dps of righthand / 10)`:

- 22 dps claw gives an average of `16` damage per Eviscerate hit
- 22 dps claw with *an* offhand weapon gives an average of `18` damage per Eviscerate hit
- 45 dps claw gives an average of `38` damage per Eviscerate hit
- 45 dps claw with *an* offhand weapon gives an average of `42` damage per Eviscerate hit

In the first case we see an increase of `2` and in the second case an increase of `4` which *could* be explained by the formula.

So we can just equip a **shield** as offhand for better survivability?

No, the damage output will be the same as if you had only a claw in your right hand (a la scenario 1).

But the increase of damage by dual-wielding is very little, why is it worth to dual-wield then?

This was done at level 2 and with no multipliers, skills... so the damage increase by dual-wielding should scale better at higher levels, better gear/skills...

I hope this answers most of your questions!

Comment: Damn, nice work. :) That I have only one upvote to give.

Comment: And if you put just 1 weapon in your offhand do weapon DPS skills do 0 damage?

Comment: Is it related to the execute chance, since the execute chance of Berserker is 10% by coincidence?

Answer (score 0):

If weapon damage is 30, and you hit for 54, it is adding close to 88% damage. 88% of 30 is 26.4.

You have to take into account the monsters armor and probably a number of other factors so I'm sure it is weapon damage + 88% of that damage.

Answer (score -1):

I just tried it about 10 times, and it seems that while you wield 2 weapons, the skill hits with both of them, each dealing 88% of their original damage.

For instance, I do 30 damage with 1 weapon, and 54 damage with the skill (hence, 166% approximately, if talking about both of the weapons' damage). But the skill doesn't seem to tell you about this effect. Maybe this skill tree is focused on wielding two weapons?

Comment: The skill does more damage than a normal attack even with only 1 weapon equipped, so this theory doesn't check out.